# How to concatenate and evaluate macro using ## operator

Tags: c, macros

I have written a  c code like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#define CHAN(n) ((0x8020##4+n) ## 20)
void main()
{
     int n = any_value;
     printf("%x",CHAN(n));
}
```

I am getting compilation error `pasting ")" and "20" does not give a valid preprocessing token` .

Actually I want to evaluate the expression with value  `n`. So let's say if I pass value of `n` as `1` than I expect output `0x8020520`. Similarly if I pass value of `n` as `8` than I expect `0x8020c20`.

If I remove `##20` from the macro than I don't get any compilation error and i get expected half output like `0x80205` or `0x8020c` My problem is I am not able to find a way to concatenate 20 after expression evaluation i.e `(0x8020##4+n)##20`. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not how the preprocessor works (It can't add and then paste). Depending on your full macro, this can easily be replaced with some maths: `CHAN(n) (0x8020020 | ((4 + (n)) << 8))`

Comment: @Artyer: You can make that an answer.

Comment: "So let's say if I pass value of n as 1 than I expect output 0x8020520. Similarly if I pass value of n as 4 than I expect 0x8020c20"  How does this make any sense? What's variable here, the shifts or the values? It can't be both at the same time. These two sentences contradict each other.

Comment: @Lundin Actually `0x8020(4+n)20` is an base address. If I want to calculate next address than it depends on value of `n`. I mean if I pass value of n as 1 than it becomes `0x8020(4+1)20=0x8020520`. Similarly if we pass `8` than it becomes `0x8020(4+8)20=0x8020c20`

Comment: But you wrote "if I pass value of n as 4 than I expect 0x8020c20". Should it say n=8? Please edit and fix.

Comment: @Lundin, You are correct. Thanks. I have corrected Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `(0x8020##4+n)`, it is parsed as these tokens: "(", "0x8020" ## "4", "+", "n", ")".

After pasting "0x8020" and "4" together, you end up with `( 0x80204 + n )`. This doesn't actually add `n` before pasting. (And how could it? The preprocessor doesn't know what a variable is, and it thinks "n" is just a 1-length string)

When you do `) ## 20`, you end up with the invalid token ")20", which doesn't make sense. So it rightfully throws an error.

It seems like you want to replace one hex digit with the value of `n`. You can easily do this with bitwise operations:

```
 #define CHAN(n) (0x8020020 | ((4 + n) << 8))
 //                     ^
```

(Where the shift moves the single hex digit represented by (4 + n) to the second place value, and `|` (bitwise or)-ing it will replace the indicated 0.

Comment: I think we should `<<` it by 8 instead of 4

Comment: But this doesn't give "if I pass value of n as 4 than I expect 0x8020c20". n=4 gives `8020820`. Turns out the question doesn't make any sense and can't be answered.